# Scroll Image in canvas from top to bottom

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

How can I scroll Image from top to bottom position. Currently, it is moving from left to right and also tried interchanging the "xpos" and "y" value but the Image is getting distorted .Any help would be appreciated.

```js
(function() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame
                || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
                || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame
                || function(callback) { window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60); };

        var canvas = document.getElementById('bg');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        var looping = false;
        var totalSeconds = 0;

        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = imageLoaded;
        img.src = 'https://preview.ibb.co/dpQ6Ak/test.jpg';

        function imageLoaded() {
            draw(0);
            startStop();
        }

        var lastFrameTime = 0;

        function startStop() {
            looping = !looping;

            if (looping) {
                lastFrameTime = Date.now();
                requestAnimationFrame(loop);
            }
        }

        function loop() {
            if (!looping) {
                return;
            }

            requestAnimationFrame(loop);

            var now = Date.now();
            var deltaSeconds = (now - lastFrameTime) / 1000;
            lastFrameTime = now;
            draw(deltaSeconds);
        }

      function draw(delta) {
            totalSeconds += delta;

            var vx = 100; // the background scrolls with a speed of 100 pixels/sec
            var numImages = Math.ceil(canvas.width / img.width) + 1;
            var xpos = totalSeconds * vx % img.width;

            context.save();
            context.translate(-xpos, 0);
            for (var i = 0; i < numImages; i++) {
                context.drawImage(img, i * img.width, 0);
            }
            context.restore();
        }
    }());
```

```html
<canvas id="bg" ></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is your answer

```js
(function() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame
                || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
                || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame
                || function(callback) { window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60); };

        var canvas = document.getElementById('bg');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        var looping = false;
        var totalSeconds = 0;

        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = imageLoaded;
        img.src = 'https://preview.ibb.co/dpQ6Ak/test.jpg';

        function imageLoaded() {
            draw(0);
            startStop();
        }

        var lastFrameTime = 0;

        function startStop() {
            looping = !looping;

            if (looping) {
                lastFrameTime = Date.now();
                requestAnimationFrame(loop);
            }
        }

        function loop() {
            if (!looping) {
                return;
            }

            requestAnimationFrame(loop);

            var now = Date.now();
            var deltaSeconds = (now - lastFrameTime) / 1000;
            lastFrameTime = now;
            draw(deltaSeconds);
        }

      function draw(delta) {
            totalSeconds += delta;

            var vx = 100; // the background scrolls with a speed of 100 pixels/sec
            var numImages = Math.ceil(canvas.height / img.height) + 1;
            var xpos = totalSeconds * vx % img.height;

            context.save();
            context.translate( 0,xpos);
            for (var i = 0; i < numImages; i++) {
                context.drawImage(img, 0,-(i * img.height));
            }
            context.restore();
        }
    }());
```

```html
<canvas id="bg" ></canvas>
```

Comment: I want to scroll Image from top to bottom position but the answer you have posted is moving Image from left to right which I have already shared

Comment: Now check, it's moving top to bottom

Comment: Thanks Man. Solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Drawing an image moving in any direction

```js
    var imageScroll = scrollImage("myCan",1.57,60);
    setTimeout(randomScroll,10000);
    function randomScroll(){
        imageScroll.setSpeed( Math.random() * 60 + 20)
          .setDirection( Math.random() * Math.PI * 2);
          
        setTimeout(randomScroll,1000 + 2000 * Math.random());
    }
        
    
    
    
    
    function scrollImage(canvasId, direction, speed, URL){
        var w, h, iW, iH;  // alias for width and height, an image W H
        var x, y;          // current image pos;
        var lastTime;      // to track frame time
        var stop = false;  // when true stop
        const rAF = requestAnimationFrame;  // Alias
        const canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);  
        if (canvas === null) { throw new ReferenceError("Can not find canvas with id : '" + canvasId + "'") }
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        const img = new Image;

        w = canvas.width = innerWidth;
        h = canvas.height = innerHeight;
        x = y = lastTime = 0;
lastTime = 0;

        img.src = URL ? URL : 'https://preview.ibb.co/dpQ6Ak/test.jpg';
        img.onload = () => { 
            iW = img.width;
            iH = img.height;
            loop(0)
         }

        function loop(time) {
            var fTime = (time - lastTime) / 1000;       // get frame time
            lastTime = time;                       
            x += Math.cos(direction) * speed * fTime ;  // update position
            y += Math.sin(direction) * speed * fTime ;
            drawImageRep(x, y);                         // draw image at x,y
            if (!stop){ requestAnimationFrame(loop) }
        }
        function drawImageRep(x,y){
            x = ((x % iW) + iW) % iW;
            y = ((y % iH) + iH) % iH;

            for(var iy = y  - iH; iy < h; iy += iH){ 
                for(var ix = x  - iW; ix < w; ix += iW){ 
                    ctx.drawImage(img, ix, iy);
                }
            }
       }
       return {
           stop(){stop = true; return this },
           setSpeed(nSpeed){ speed = nSpeed; return this },
           setDirection(nDirection) { direction = nDirection; return this }, 
       }
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="myCan"></canvas>
```